# How can I use g:render with my g:each variable from a Map collection?

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a `def statusMap = HashMap<String, List<MyItem>>()` that gets passed into my gsp page.

In my gsp page I have the following:

```
<g:each var="myList" in="${statusMap}">
  <div id="pending_list" class="onTop">
    <g:render template="/list" model="['list':"${myList.value}", 'listSize':"${myList.value.size()}"]" />
  </div>
</g:each>
```

But I can't seem to correctly pass `myList.value` and `myList.value.size()` into my template.  I think my quotes are wrong somehow but I'm not sure.

How can I correctly pass myList.value and myList.value.size() into  the list template through the model?

Comment: Have you tried? <g:render template="/list" model="['list': myList.value, 'listSize': myList.value.size()]" />

Comment: I just tried it, it didn't work.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: I just realized you are doing this with a Map. Are you trying to iterate over all the keys within the map? If so I can post an answer on how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a map your itteration is based on keys within that Map. So the basic syntax looks like this:

```
<g:each in=${yourCoolMap.entrySet()}" var="entry">
${entry.key} = ${entry.value}
</g:each>
```

Thus, your code will look something like this:

```
<g:each var="myList" in="${statusMap.entrySet()}">
  <div id="pending_list" class="onTop">
    <g:render template="/list" model="['list': myList.value, 'listSize': myList.value.size()]" />
  </div>
</g:each>
```